# In parameter query grid not loading loader on curent item select in asp.net mvc application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am facing an issue in with a parameter query grid. When I click on the current item and items display data. I put loader on an AJAX call but the loader is not working properly. It binds data not from the current item - it displays data from the previous item selected.

```js
function tree_grid(ID) {
  $("#divLoading").show();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Schedule/GetAllPresentation',
    data: "{ scheduleID: '" + ID + "',YearId:" + YearId + ",CompanyId:" + CompanyId + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(response) {
      $("#divLoading").hide();
      var data1 = [];
      data1 = $.parseJSON(response);
      data = data1;
    },
    error: function() {
      swal("", "Error in Data !", "error");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Don´t understand your problem, maybe you run into error:function and therefore the loader not gets hidden?

Comment: 1) Remove `async: false`. It is ***incredibly*** bad practice. 2) Use an object literal instead of hacking together JSON - which is incidentally using invalid syntax 3) There is nothing here which is related to your problem. That seems to be centered around how you invoke the `tree_grid()` function and what the value of `ID` is. As such, we cannot answer this question without you adding more detail to it.

Comment: Re. points 1 & 2 in my previous comment, this is what your code should look like: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/wm6vhyng/. But as I mentioned in point 3, this isn't going to fix the problem you have.